# Read list of unknown type from user input Haskell:

Tags: haskell, types, type-conversion, typeclass

Say I have the following function:

```
readList :: IO [Int]
readList = do
  putStrLn "Please enter the list as a string"
  putStrLn "Example: input of '1 2 3 4 5' will map to [1,2,3,4,5]"
  line <- getLine
  return $ map read $ words line

 printNaive :: [Int] -> IO ()                                                                                                                                                         
 printNaive xs = putStrLn "The maximum surpasser count is:" >> putStrLn "0"

 main :: IO ()
 main = readList >>= printNaive
```

This function works as expected. Now lets say I was going to extend this code to be more generic, and read in a line of any type of thing as a list:

```
readList :: (Read a, Int a) -> IO [a]
readList = do
  putStrLn "Please enter the list as a string"
  putStrLn "Example: input of '1 2 3 4 5' will map to [1,2,3,4,5]"
  line <- getLine
  return $ map read $ words line

 printNaive :: (Eq a) => [a] -> IO ()                                                                                                                                                         
 printNaive xs = putStrLn "The maximum surpasser count is:" >> putStrLn "0"

 main :: IO ()
 main = readList >>= printNaive
```

This fails with:

```
 Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘Lib.readList’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Read a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Read Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        instance Read Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        instance Read a => Read (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus four instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
```

How would I go about writing this code, given I really don't care what type of thing it is as long as it conforms to `Eq`.

Additionally, say I wanted to provide a facility to specify what type the list is going to contain.  (through another getLine say).

How would I extract a type from `getLine`, and how would I then cast every element in the `map read $ words line` to that particular type.

Comment: Please post the exact code that lead to this error. Don't take shortcuts during minimization and guess which code. Verify, by putting it in a separate file and checking that it does, indeed, give you the error you expect.

Comment: You can probably just remove the type signature from you function and ask ghc for the most general type by using ghci, loading your program and typing `:t readList`

Comment: edited question to include more code as the original set was not, in fact, a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @AbrahamP You still have not succeeded in providing the code that matches the presented error.

Comment: There"s simply no way to not care what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong is in this line:

```
readList :: (Read a, Int a) -> IO [a]
```

What you probably want to get at with `(Read a, Int a)` is a type class constranit for the type `a`, meaning you want it to be readable and you want it to be some sort of integer.

Firstly you wrote your constraint wrong. A typeclass constraint is given before a `=>` not a `->`. Secondly `Int` is not a type class. Maybe try using `Integral`?

So your type signature should look like this:

```
readList :: (Read a, Integral a) => IO [a]
```

**EDIT:** A caveat is, however, that the `a` in the type signature has to be decided at compile time. In the first example in your question it would work out because the type of `printNaive` fixes `a` to be `Int`. That is not generally the case, however.

Comment: but what about Characters, or custom comparable things? Say I wanted a function that could read both:

'a b c d e f' into ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] and '1 2 3 4 5' into ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

Comment: This answer addresses the syntax error in the presented code.  However, the presented code does not match the question or the error message.  @AbrahamP You simply can not read any type of data to be determined at run-time.  Types must be statically known at compile time.

Comment: @Thomas you are of course right. But in the specific code of the question, the above modification will still work out fine. I'll edit the answer to include your remark.